# an error is displayed OSError at /images/create/[Errno 38] Function not implementedRequest Method:POST

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, termux

here is the form code:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Image

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

from django.utils.text import slugify

import requests

class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Image

        fields = ['title', 'url', 'description']

        widgets = {

            'url': forms.HiddenInput,

        }

    def clean_url(self):

        url = self.cleaned_data['url']

        valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']

        extension = url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()

        if extension not in valid_extensions:

            raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not ' \

                                        'match valid image extensions.')

        return url

    def save(self, force_insert=False,

                   force_update=False,

                   commit=True):

        image = super().save(commit=False)

        image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']

        name = slugify(image.title)

        extension = image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()

        image_name = f'{name}.{extension}'

        # download image from the given URL

        response = requests.get(image_url)

        image.image.save(image_name,

                         ContentFile(response.content),

                         save=False)

        if commit:

            image.save()

        return image




here is the views.py:



from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.contrib import messages

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from django.http import JsonResponse

from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, \

                                  PageNotAnInteger

from .forms import ImageCreateForm

from .models import Image

@login_required

def image_create(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # form is sent

        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            # form data is valid

            cd = form.cleaned_data

            new_image = form.save(commit=False)

            # assign current user to the item

            new_image.user = request.user

            new_image.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')

            # redirect to new created image detail view

            return redirect(new_image.get_absolute_url())

    else:

        # build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET

        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    return render(request,

                  'images/image/create.html',

                  {'section': 'images',

                   'form': form})

def image_detail(request, id, slug):

    image = get_object_or_404(Image, id=id, slug=slug)

    return render(request,

                  'images/image/detail.html',

                  {'section': 'images',

                   'image': image})

@login_required

@require_POST

def image_like(request):

    image_id = request.POST.get('id')

    action = request.POST.get('action')

    if image_id and action:

        try:

            image = Image.objects.get(id=image_id)

            if action == 'like':

                image.users_like.add(request.user)

            else:

                image.users_like.remove(request.user)

            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})

        except Image.DoesNotExist:

            pass

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})

@login_required

def image_list(request):

    images = Image.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(images, 8)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    images_only = request.GET.get('images_only')

    try:

        images = paginator.page(page)

    except PageNotAnInteger:

        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page

        images = paginator.page(1)

    except EmptyPage:

        if images_only:

            # If AJAX request and page out of range

            # return an empty page

            return HttpResponse('')

        # If page out of range return last page of results

        images = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if images_only:

        return render(request,

                      'images/image/list_images.html',

                      {'section': 'images',

                       'images': images})

    return render(request,

                  'images/image/list.html',

                   {'section': 'images',

                    'images': images})



here is the models code:





from django.db import models

from django.utils.text import slugify

from django.conf import settings

class Image(models.Model):

  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='images_created',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,blank=True)

  url = models.URLField(max_length=2000)

  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')

  description = models.TextField(blank=True)

  created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

  users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='images_liked',blank=True)

  class Meta:

    indexes = [

    models.Index(fields=['-created']),

    ]

    ordering = ['-created']

  def __str__(self):

    return self.title

  

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.slug:

      self.slug = slugify(self.title)

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)



HTML code:




{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Bookmark an image{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <h1>Bookmark an image</h1>

  <img src="{{ request.GET.url }}" class="image-preview">

  <form method="post">

    {{ form.as_p }}

    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" value="Bookmark it!">

  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

just in case I program on my phone (`Acode`). I run the code on `Termux`